# How to find values in one column that maps (directly or indirectly) to values in another column?

Tags: python, mapping

I have a dataset given as follows:

```
<t>Pokemon    Evolves to<\t> 
<t>Pichu      Pickachu<\t> 
<t>Pickachu   Raichu<\t> 
<t>Bulbasaur  Venusaur<\t>
```

I want the output as a list of lists giving me an inner pokemon and all the pokemon it evolves to. The output should be something like this: 
[[Pichu, Pickachu, Raichu], [Bulbasaur, Venusaur]]

How do I go about it? Do I need to create a tree type structure? Or is there any other way?

This is for Python 3. I've tried looking for similar problems but couldn't find anything conclusive.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by making a dictionary containing the possible transformations a Pokemon can make. So, as a key we have the Pokemon on the left-hand side of your dataset, and as its value we have the Pokemon it can evolve to, as a tuple:

```
evolves = {"Pichu": ("Pickachu",), "Pickachu": ("Raichu",), "Bulbasaur": ("Venusaur",)}
```

Let X(A) be the Pokemons that Pokemon A can evolve to.

Now, you can:

1. While there were changes

   2. For every Pokemon A

      3. Consider every Pokemon B in X(A)
      4. Take the set X(B) consisting of the Pokemons B can evolve to
      5. If the set X(A) + X(B) != X(A), add X(B) to X(A) and remove X(B)

Comment: `code`import csv
    if __name__=="__main__":
            mydict = {}
            reader = csv.reader(open("pokemon_evolution.csv", "r"))
            for i, rows in enumerate(reader):
                if i == 0: continue
                 k = rows[0]
                v = rows[1]
                if not k in mydict:
                    mydict[k] = [v]
                else:
                    mydict[k].append(v)`code`


I have created the dictionary. Please help me with how to code the next part.